# SSE messages being "stored" by client's gateway server until 16kB reached

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I'm sending json messages (about 1kB each) to a client to display, using a stream from a php script which sends a message every few seconds.  Everything has been working fine for years until the company upgraded the desktops from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  I don't think this change itself made a difference, but whatever setup they are using to connect to the outside world meant that no messages were coming through (despite a connection being setup successfully by the browser), then about 16 messages at once.

Having played around, sending dummy messages of various lengths and watching the URL that is the stream (rather than the UI URL), it is obvious that the messages are being held "somewhere" until they amount for 16kB and then the whole lot come at once.

I've temporarily resolved this by padding the message with 15,000 zeros on the end, but obviously that isn't ideal as I'm now transfering 16 times the data.

The headers I'm sending are:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache\n\n");
```

followed by the message and "\n\n".

Is there anything I can add to this to force the data to be streamed right the way through to the client in real time?

Comment: Are you able to get the headers the client is receiving (e.g. from developer tools in the user's browser)? There might be some mention of the proxy they are using. You might at least be able to see if some of your headers are getting stripped out.

Comment: The header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" is being added between it leaving my server and arriving on the client browser.  The same header is not present when I look at it on a non-corporate PC.

I have tried adding that header to my content myself and specifying the length of the message and using \r\n, but this doesn't seem to make any difference